# What are the advantages a user gets after making a site through Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

I know that Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, where users come together to build new Q&A sites. What are the advantages that a user gets when he Propose one site in it, (for a specific area of interest) and then shifting it up through `define`, `commit`, `beta` stages and finally to a working site? Will the user get any privileges?

Comment: the main advantage is that one can be part of shaping a site and putting it on the way.

Comment: @juergend I know that well B) . But are there any specific benefits?

Comment: It's the only way to make a new Stack Exchange site, so basically, if there's a topic you want to see a site on and it doesn't exist, the specific benefit is a site may then exist.

Comment: What kind of "specific benefits" are you talking about? Cash? Prizes? Recognition? Extra influence on the new site?

Comment: I mean something like moderator benefits.

Answer (score 4):

The benefit is that the site the user wanted to be a part of becomes a real site. It gets put up on the internet and has a community to participate, and a company to host/maintain it. They get to define the site, and refine the definition along the way. As long as they participate throughout the process, they will have the respect of that site's community as the user who founded the site/community.

The Area51 reputation earned from this doesn't hurt either, but isn't really a benefit/advantage to creating a successful proposal.

Answer (score 2):

The most important benefit, as juergen d said in a comment, is that he helps build a successful site (assuming he does).

Secondarily, there are badges (Precognitive and Beta) on the new site for people who participated in the early stages.

Also secondarily, activity on Area 51, such as recruiting people to proposals, earns reputation on Area 51.